# Error in UK visa application already submitted

Tags: applications

I have already submitted my UK visa application and I find that I made a mistake in the question of how much do you spend monthly , I did not notice it is in GBP and  I wrote the amount under the impression it is EGP . What shall I do my , shall I cancel application and refund or shall I correct it manually , pls help , ,my appointment is tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

Tomorrow when you go for your appointment mention this to the clerk and follow their advice.